# how to Ignore definitions (VS2008)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, enums

i have some sourcecode that I want to compile with VS2008 but there are many errors i have to fix.
Now there are some Enums like:

```
enum
{
BACKGROUND  = 0x00000001,
WEAPON      = 0x00000002,
TRANSPARENT = 0x00000004
}
```

The problem is that TRANSPARENT is defined as:

```
#define TRANSPARENT         1
```

in WinGDI.h

That will cause a compile error like:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'constant'
```

Is it possible to fix that error without renaming the field in the enum and without removing the WinGDI.h from the includes (I don't know where it's included..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
#undef TRANSPARENT
```

but that may cause errors elsewhere, if the WinGDI TRANSPARENT is used afterwards. A (messy) workaround could be:

```
#ifdef TRANSPARENT
#define _TRANSPARENT TRANSPARENT
#undef TRANSPARENT
#endif
```

and after your code:

```
#ifdef _TRANSPARENT
#define TRANSPARENT _TRANSPARENT
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the value TRANSPARENT from WinGDI.h, you can simply add:

`#undef TRANSPARENT`

before the enum (this is only a workaround, better rename the TRANSPARENT in the enum).